# Find an user by their hashed token

Tags: php, sql, hash, access-token, salt

I want to implement a token-based authentication system that is strongly resistant to insider attacks. That is, someone who has read-only access to the code and the database shouldn't be able to use someone else's token. It means that JWT is not the way to go, because if someone knows the secret key of the token signatures (that is stored in plain text on the server) they can compromise the tokens of everybody (provided that they know the payload of the user). Besides, I want something simpler to implement than OpenID/OAuth.

Thus, I thought about having access tokens for each user stored in the database. Each one of them would have a time-to-live of 1 day. But if you know the token of an user, 1 day is more than enough to do something nasty with it, like deleting the account for example. Hence, I want to add another security layer and hash the tokens in the database.

The problem is, the `password_hash()` function of PHP uses salt so it is not deterministic. What it means is that I cannot do that:

```
// Insert a new user
$token = generateToken(size=32);
$tokenHash = password_hash($token, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `User` (username, password_hash, token_hash)
VALUES (:username, :password_hash, :token_hash)
";
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
  ":username" => $username,
  ":password_hash" => $paswordHash
  ":token_hash" => $tokenHash
]);

// Find an user with their token
$tokenHash = password_hash($token, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE token_hash = :token_hash";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([":token_hash" => $tokenHash]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Indeed, `$tokenHash` will in practice never be equal to the value stored in the database, and the correct function to do this comparison is `password_verify()`. But retrieving all the users of the database and using `password_verify()` for each of them would be way too inefficient.

What is the correct way to find an user (or more generally a database record) using an hashed value in his columns?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why would you want to do this in the first place?, user passwords can be the same across many users right?

Comment: I wanted to simplify my question, but in fact I won't `password_hash()` passwords but access tokens instead, that are stored in the database and that are securely unique given 2 different users. Thus I want to know if an access token that I receive is valid or not. I don't want to store them in plain text because I want my authentication system to be very secure.

Comment: ahh okay, it's quite important to name that aswell, since password unhashing and then using it in a query seems suspicous

Comment: What you posted for code won't work. You're trying to select with the hashing function instead of the one to verify with. If that isn't what you're really using, you will have to edit. This for me, makes it unclear.

Comment: I know that it doesn't work, I wrote "I cannot do that:" just before.

Comment: `I won't password_hash() passwords but access tokens ` - please edit the question to indicate the actual problem you're trying to solve - readers shouldn't need to read the comments to figure out it's actually different than the question asked (-1). Since the app will want to lookup users by access-token - hashing them as a password actively prevents doing that. It's probably a good idea to look for existing examples of the intended objective - [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql#L24-L32).

Comment: Ok I re-explained my problem and edited quite substantially the post. I will also post an answer later on.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the question. `strongly resistant to insider attacks` - that is not a problem you can solve with application code. If someone has access to the code, database and or access logs - they can do anything users can do (and more). The approach you are taking seems to have exactly the same level of security whether this extra hash mechanism existing or not. Which is something [that's been said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472467/php-hash-function-without-salt#comment103278284_58472467)

Comment: "and more", but what more? My database wouldn't contain anything sensitive that the users aren't supposed to know, I just don't want that someone with read-access to the server can use the token of someone else (and thus delete their account for instance). As I said in the post you linked, I'm doing this as part of an university project where we develop a webapp, then we give read-access to other students and they have to find a breach. If you have access to a plain token, you can do a masquerade, whereas with a hashed token you have to reverse-engineer it first.

Comment: `then we give read-access to other students` - read access to what? Do you not think these facts/details should be in the question? In the real world it's common to have an auditor have access _to the code_ to try and find an exploit - anyone who has access (even read only) to a server and/or unreacted logs can do pretty much anything they want, "and more" includes everything you're saying you're trying to prevent in addition to acts such as connecting to the database and truncating all the tables, finding s3 buckets an deleting them, collecting all user's email addresses and spamming them etc

Comment: This question is currently a classic example of the [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and therefore unclear (VTC) - please update your question.

Comment: I added the mention of read-only access in the question, but I refute that it is a XY problem, I described the exact problem here: how to find a database record using a salted value. Even considering there remain (and there always will be) security breaches, I uphold that it's a bit disingenuous to assert that the security is exactly the same whether or not I'm hashing the token (I doubt your everyday improvised hacker IT student is able to meddle with database logs). I'm not storing anything sensitive in the database (unless you consider RSS feeds sensitive), so spamming users is impossible.

Comment: I suggest you’ve misunderstood the assignment. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, good luck to you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, one cannot use a salt to create searchable hashes. Hashing with a fast unsalted algorithm like SHA-256 is perfectly fine though, **as long as your tokens are very strong**. This means the token should contain at least 24 random characters of the alphabet `0..9, a..z, A..Z`.

Salting and key-stretching are measures for weak user passwords, to prevent dictionary attacks and to make brute-force attacks unpractical. Strong random tokens can be hashed without this precautions.

I wrote some [example code](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) how such tokens could be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions:

**1. Use an hash function that doesn't have salt**

With the PHP `hash()` function, the result will always be the same as there is no randomly generated salt. This way you can compare the 2 token hashes like so:

```
// Insert a new user
$token = generateToken(size=32);
$tokenHash = hash("sha256", $token); // Use hash() instead of password_hash()
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `User` (username, password_hash, token_hash)
VALUES (:username, :password_hash, :token_hash)
";
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
  ":username" => $username,
  ":password_hash" => $paswordHash
  ":token_hash" => $tokenHash
]);

// Find an user with their token
$tokenHash = hash("sha256", $token); // Same here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE token_hash = :token_hash";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([":token_hash" => $tokenHash]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**2. Create your own `password_verify()` in SQL**

You can write your own bcrypt verification function in the database and use it in the second query:

```
// Find an user with their token
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE password_verify(:token, token_hash)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([":token" => $token]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```